# Вопрос из задачника

Tags: javascript

Число называется счастливым если при складывании, суммы обеих сторон числа ровны друг другу.На пример։A=1230 считается счастливым потому что сумма первой половины числа ровна второй половине (1+2 | 3+0).Нужно написать функцию solution которое получает число и возвращает true если число счастливое, false в обратном случае.

---

Нужно реализовать код под 4 варианта

- на входе:x=[1230],на выходе:true
- на входе:x=[239017],на выходе:false
- на входе:x=[134008],на выходе:true
- на входе:x=[10],на выходе:false

```js
x=[239017];
   function solution(x){
        let newArr = [];
    for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            let temp = x[i] + x[i+1];
            newArr.push(temp);
        }
        if(newArr[i]===newArr[i+1]){
            return true
        } 
            return false
         
    }
   }
    console.log(solution(x))
```

---

Как реализовать код правильно

Comment: а что делает приведенный код? Затрудняюсь понять его логику.

Comment: *если его обе стороны ровны друг другу* На самом деле должна быть равна сумма цифр...

Comment: @Эникейщик, приведённый код,то как я пытался решить задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А число в качестве аргумента функции передаётся именно как массив?

Тогда как-то так можно сделать:

```js
function solution(num) {
  let x = num.join(''); //преобразуем массив в строку
  let left = 0;
  let right = 0;
  //в цикле проходим по строке с двух сторон
  for(let i = 0, j = x.length-1; i < x.length/2; i++, j--) {
    left += Number(x[i]); //складываем левую часть
    right += Number(x[j]); //складываем правую часть
  }
  if(left == right) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(solution([134008]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так получилось, проверки корректности входных данных нет:

```js
let test = x => 0 === String(x).split('')  
                               .map((x, i, a) => x * (a.length/2 > i ? -1 : 1))
                               .reduce((a, x) => a + x);

[1230, 239017, 134008, 10].forEach(x => console.log(x, ' -> ', test(x)));
```

В этом решении число представляется как строка, разбивается на символы, после чего каждый из символов приводится к числу, а те числа, индекс которых в исходном масиве больше половины длины массива, умножаются на -1. Потом сумма всех этих элементов сравнивается с 0.

Answer (score 1):

Я вот такое решение нашёл :)

```js
//на входе:x=[1230],на выходе:true
//на входе:x=[239017],на выходе:false
//на входе:x=[134008],на выходе:true
//на входе:x=[10],на выходе:false

let xn = [1230, 239017, 134008, 10];

function solution(x) {
  x.forEach(elem => {
    let a = elem.toString().split('');
    let res1 = a.slice(0, a.length / 2).reduce((acc, cur) => +acc + +cur);
    let res2 = a.slice(a.length / 2, a.length).reduce((acc, cur) => +acc + +cur)
    console.log(elem, res1 === res2);
  });
}

solution(xn);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function div(a, b) {
  return (a - a % b) / b
}

function solution(num) {
  let len = num.toString().length;
  const half = div(len, 2);

  let a = 0;
  let b = 0;

  let count = 0;
  let flag = true;
  while (num > 0) {
    if (count === half) {
      flag = !flag;
      if (len % 2 > 0) {
        num = div(num, 10);
      }
    }

    if (flag) {
      b += num % 10;
    } else {
      a += num % 10;
    }

    num = div(num, 10);
    count++;
  }

  return a === b;
}

console.log(solution(1230));  // true
console.log(solution(239017));  // false
console.log(solution(134008));  // true
console.log(solution(10));  // false
console.log(solution(112));  // false
console.log(solution(35108));  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isHappy(number) {
  const arrayOfNumbers = String(number).split('');

  if (arrayOfNumbers.length % 2 !== 0) return false;

  const average = arrayOfNumbers.length / 2;

  const leftSideSum = arrayOfNumbers.slice(0, average).reduce((res, num) => Number(res) + Number(num));
  const rightSideSum = arrayOfNumbers.slice(average).reduce((res, num) => Number(res) + Number(num));


  return leftSideSum === rightSideSum
}
```